# How am I mis-using the || logical operator in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, logic

```
var user = prompt("Prose prose prose. Do you SCREAM, TURN AROUND, or RUN").toUpperCase();

switch (user) {
    case 'SCREAM':
        var choice1 = prompt("Prose prose prose. Do you TURN AROUND, PASS OUT, or USE MAGIC").toUpperCase();
            if (choice1 === "TURN AROUND" || "TURN") {
                console.log("Prose prose prose!")

            } else if (choice1 === "PASS_OUT" || "PASS" || "FAINT" || "FEINT") {
                console.log("Prose prose prose.")

            } else if (choice1 === "USE_MAGIC" || "MAGIC" || "SPELL" || "WIZARDRY") {
                console.log("Prose prose prose.")

            } else if (choice1 === "4" && "2" || "42") {
                console.log("Congratulations, You have chosen the secret option! You win!")
            } else {
                console.log("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Try again!")
            }
        break;

 //imagine default state and rest of code are here
```

So this is just a snippet of a very basic code I'm working on. The problem I'm having is that every time I choose any of the "`PASS OUT`" or "`USE MAGIC`" options, the choice automatically defaults to the "`TURN AROUND`" option. Now I found out that if I only have two logical operators for those `else if` statements, the problem goes away. But from what I've been reading on the internet, there should not be a limit to how many things I can put between logical operators. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See TJ's answer below.  Javascript isn't English, you need to say EXACTLY what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
if (choice1 === "TURN AROUND" || choice1 === "TURN") {
```

...and so on. E.g., you have to have your comparison on each side of the `||` operator. See below for why.

But in this case, I'd probably use another `switch` (possibly in a separate function, to keep things from getting too complex), or possibly a lookup table.

---

Your original expression is evaluated like this:

```
if ((choice1 === "TURN AROUND") || "TURN") {
```

...which for `choice1 = "FOO"` (for instance) becomes:

```
if (false || "TURN") {
```

...because `choice1` is not `"TURN AROUND"`. That then becomes:

```
if ("TURN") {
```

...because of the way the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) works. Because that's truthy, you branch into the `if` block even though `choice1` doesn't match either alternative.

Comment: or `["PASS_OUT", "PASS", "FAINT", "FEINT"].indexOf(choice1)`

Comment: My goodness, 3 minutes and my question is already answered :) Thank you! Javascript makes me feel like a fool once again

Comment: @Georgi: Just continue to embrace learning (as you seem to be doing) and you'll be fine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that the || operator tests if the statement on the left is true, or if the statement on the right is true. So in case of your first if statement, it tests if choice1 === "TURN AROUND" is true OR if "TURN" is true. And since you just check for a string it is always true.

What you have to do here is, to always check against choice 1 like this:

```
if(choice1 === "TURN AROUND" || choice1 === "TURN"){
    console.log("Prose prose prose!");
} else if (choice1 === "PASS OUT" || choice1 === "PASS" || choice1 === "FAINT" || choice1 === "FEINT"){
    console.log("Prose prose prose.");
}  // and so on
[...]
```

You could simplify your code by using adeneo's suggestion:

```
if(["TURN AROUND", "TURN"].indexOf(choice1) !== -1){
    console.log("Prose prose prose!");
} else if(["PASS OUT", "PASS", "FAINT", "FEINT"].indexOf(choice1) !== -1){
    console.log("Prose prose prose.");
} // and so on
```